# Cannot find ReportViewer and ScriptManager controls in .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: reporting-services, scriptmanager, .net-framework-version, report-viewer2010

I have a project developed on `.NET Framework 2.0`. Now I want to include an `SSRS` Report to this project but I am unable to find `ScriptManager` and `ReportViewer` controls in my toolbox. These are available in .NET Framework 4.0, so what do I have to do to create SSRS report for Framework 2.0

Answer (score 1):

.Net Framework 2.0 was released ten years ago, so ideally you should look to upgrade to a more recent version. However if you are stuck with 2.0 then you will need to use the Report Viewer control from SQL Server 2005, which can be downloaded from the Microsoft website:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21916